# How to access to call log and sms from web application through browser (android and/or iOS)?

Tags: android, ios, browser, web-applications, contacts

We are building web-application which helps you to sort your contacts by various ways. One important data-source for that is call log (history) and SMS-log.
Is there a way to access that from browser not developing application?
I'm looking possibilities for browsers like:

- Android built-in browser;
- Google chrome for mobile (Android and iOS)
- Safari for iOS

Thank you for any guidance and idea you can share!

Comment: I am not aware of any Android browser that makes this data available, which is good, for obvious privacy and security reasons.

Comment: What about Instant Apps?
https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/index.html

Comment: No, sorry, Instant Apps cannot hold the relevant permissions for accessing that data.

Answer (score 3):

**No**, it is definitely not possible. As *CommonsWare* says, it would be a huge privacy issue if websites could access that kind of information.

If I can find any sources to back up my statement of fact I will edit my post.